# SQL auto increment with base64

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if it is possible to create a table in `MS SQL` which had an id of `base64` and which auto incremented?

Right now we can do something like this

```
create table tb(
     _id int identity(1,1)
)
```

but what about something like this?

```
create table tb(
     _id base64 identity(1,1)
)
```

Comment: Don't confuse *data* with *representations*. There's nothing to stop you using a normal identity column and then *formatting* the value in base 64 for presentation purposes. (You could even add a computed column alongside the `_id` column, if you commonly want the base 64 format available down at the database level)

Comment: Above all ,what is your actual requirement,which lead you to even think of it.

Comment: Lik YouTube I have an id in the url, and I don't want people to just increment that id in order to go through all the items. Unlike YouTube I don't have a "trillion-billion" items ;-)

Comment: Do you also have people unable to realise that if you have items `a` and `c`, there's a strong possibility that there'll be a `b` and it might be worth checking for a `d` also? Because unless that's the high-point of the intelligence of your users, base 64 isn't going to gain you anything here.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just proof of concept:

1. Create Function:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION [TempFunc] 
   (
       @Id int
   )
   RETURNS nvarchar(max)
   AS
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @Id_Binary varbinary(MAX) = CONVERT(varbinary(64), @Id)

       RETURN CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Id_Binary"))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
   END
   ```
2. Create table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Temp (
       Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
       [Id_Base64]  AS (dbo.TempFunc(Id)),
       Value nvarchar(max)
   )
   ```
3. Use:

   ```
   INSERT INTO Temp
   VALUES
   (N'aaaa'),
   (N'bbbb'),
   (N'cccc')

   SELECT *
   FROM Temp AS t

   Id          Id_Base64  Value
   ----------- ---------- ----------
   1           AAAAAQ==   aaaa
   2           AAAAAg==   bbbb
   3           AAAAAw==   cccc
   ```

Or, use [NEWSEQUENTIALID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
    Id uniqueidentifier DEFAULT(NEWSEQUENTIALID()),
    Value nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp 
([Value])
VALUES
(N'aaaa'),
(N'bbbb'),
(N'cccc')

SELECT *
FROM #Temp AS t

Id                                   Value
------------------------------------ ----------
A6FD44E0-E611-E611-80E9-001DD8B71C43 aaaa
A7FD44E0-E611-E611-80E9-001DD8B71C43 bbbb
A8FD44E0-E611-E611-80E9-001DD8B71C43 cccc
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of computed column you could create a view:

```
CREATE TABLE tb(
     _id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,col VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO tb(col) VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d');
GO

CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT *
FROM tb t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(_id AS VARBINARY(MAX))
             FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64) s(base64_id);
GO             

SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/JULG36407)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════╦═══════════╗
║ _id ║ col ║ base64_id ║
╠═════╬═════╬═══════════╣
║   1 ║ a   ║ AAAAAQ==  ║
║   2 ║ b   ║ AAAAAg==  ║
║   3 ║ c   ║ AAAAAw==  ║
║   4 ║ d   ║ AAAABA==  ║
╚═════╩═════╩═══════════╝
```

---

> *Like YouTube I have an id in the url, and I don't want people to just increment that id in order to go through all the items. Unlike YouTube I don't have a "trillion-billion" items*

Then `base64` will not protect you at all. `IDENTITY` is incremental by nature and masking it is very easy to overcome.